# Extensions not showing on Extensions tab of Add-ons Manager in Firefox 12

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I don't know what happened but my list of extensions does not show up on the extensions tab of the Add-ons Manager on my Firefox 12.

Is there any `about:config` settings to show the extensions or some fix?

Comment: To clarify, any installed add-ons are still visible elsewhere and still work?

Comment: Yes installed add-ons are still visible and they still work. To name a few, Firebug, Xmarks, WebDeveloper Tools, WebDeveloper Tools Toggle, Proxy Bonanza, FirePicker, ColorZilla, VideoHelper

Answer (score 1):

I have closed Firefox, then I have deleted some files from profile folder (make a backup first):

extension.ini and extension.sqlite

Restart Firefox, it will ask to reinstall every extension.

Profile folder: "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\profile folder"

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out the way to fix, let's use MozBackup to backup the entire of your Mozilla Firefox profile, including extensions. After that, create a new profile and restore the backup.

http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/

That's it!